# AWS ECS fail to launch windows container with fargate

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

In my ECS cluster, I am unable to deploy a Windows container with Fargate.

I have simplified my task by putting everything I need directly into my image, which I then store in my ECR repository. My task has only one instruction to launch a container with my image.

A small clarification with this process, I have successfully launched Linux containers without any issues; the problem only arises with Windows containers.

This is the error I encounter every time I try to launch my container: CannotStartContainerError: **CannotStartContainerError: hcs::System::CreateProcess 1-2: The system cannot find the file specified.: unknown.**

When I launch the container locally with 'docker run -it myimage,' the container starts and functions correctly.
This is my task :

```
{
"family": "mycontainer",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "mycontainer",
        "image": "1.dkr.ecr.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/mycontainer:latest",
        "cpu": 0,
        "portMappings": [],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "volumesFrom": []
    }
],
"executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1:role/docker-cluster",
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
],
"cpu": "4096",
"memory": "16384"
}
```